# Use enum form setInterval() causing exception?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use `enum` from `setInterval()`.
e.g:

```
declare global {
    enum En_Sch_Mode {
        Daily = 1,
        Manually = 4,
        Sensor = 5
    }
}

export class DeviceInfoEx {
 private m_time_handel: any;
 private m: DeviceInfo;
    constructor() {
        this.timer_check = this.timer_check.bind(this);
        this.m_time_handel = setInterval(this.timer_check, 1000);
    }

    public timer_check(): void {
        if (this.m.schedulemode === En_Sch_Mode.Daily) {
            console.log("hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

In the case I'm getting an exception:

```
if (this.m.schedulemode === En_Sch_Mode.Daily) 

Exception has occurred: ReferenceError

ReferenceError: En_Sch_Mode is not defined

    at DeviceInfoEx.timer_check (d:\tfshomeprojects\Node.js\smartpow_ts\src\model\DeviceInfoEx.ts:80:37)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
```

Comment: I dont use typescript but in flow you need a `:` or `=` after you set a type.  Maybe typescript doesnt need that though who knows

Comment: Cannot reproduce that on the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html). What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: Version **2.6.2**

Comment: Hello Ghasem ;-)
Define enumeration as follows
`export enum En_Sch_Mode` 
And remove `declare global` block

Comment: hi mohammad ,thank you for your help ,**it worked well**:)

Comment: @MohammadDayyan Is right. By using `declare global` you essentially say to typescript **Please assume that these symbols exist at runtime**, preventing typescript from actually generating output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your enum as follows:

```
export enum En_Sch_Mode {
    Daily = 1,
    Manually = 4,
    Sensor = 5
}
```

`Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.`

If you are looking for a namespace, do it as follows:

```
namespace myNameSpace{
    export enum En_Sch_Mode {
        Daily = 1,
        Manually = 4,
        Sensor = 5
    }
}

let enSchMode = myNameSpace.En_Sch_Mode.Daily;
console.log(enSchMode);
```

You can test your typescript validity here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`declare` means there is elsewere in javascript a enum En_Sch_Mode defined. 
Like this:

```
var En_Sch_Mode;
(function (En_Sch_Mode) {
    En_Sch_Mode[En_Sch_Mode["Daily"] = 1] = "Daily";
    En_Sch_Mode[En_Sch_Mode["Manually"] = 4] = "Manually";
    En_Sch_Mode[En_Sch_Mode["Sensor"] = 5] = "Sensor";
})(En_Sch_Mode || (En_Sch_Mode = {}));
```

so maybe you want:

```
enum En_Sch_Mode {
    Daily = 1,
    Manually = 4,
    Sensor = 5
}

// Your "if" compiles in JavaScript to:
if (this.m.schedulemode === En_Sch_Mode.Daily) {
```

or

```
const enum En_Sch_Mode {
    Daily = 1,
    Manually = 4,
    Sensor = 5
}

// Your "if" compiles in JavaScript to:
if (this.m.schedulemode === 1 /* Daily */) {
```